# telegram bot api 5.1.0 SLF4J помогитие

Tags: java, telegram

Всем салют. Поясните грамотно новичку-самоучке.Пытаюсь запустить каркас ТГ бота на Джава,api 5.1.0 ,юзаю Maven,получаю следующую ошибку:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Из интернетов узнал,что нужно скачать и "добавить в путь класса" slf4j.
Как именно его добавить в "путь класса"? И что ещё у меня не так?
Я новичёк в програмировании,на библиотеке 3.5 ,каркас запускался,работал,реагировал на вводимые сообщения. Что тут может быть не так ?

Код класса Bot(без токена):

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;


public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    /**
     * Метод для приема сообщений.
     * @param update Содержит сообщение от пользователя.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        String message = update.getMessage().getText();
        sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), message);
        
    }

    /**
     * Метод для настройки сообщения и его отправки.
     * @param chatId id чата
     * @param s Строка, которую необходимот отправить в качестве сообщения.
     */
    public synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId, String s) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(s);
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
             System.out.println(e);
             

        }
    }

    /**
     * Метод возвращает имя бота, указанное при регистрации.
     * @return имя бота
     */
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "SBKbot";
    }

    /**
     * Метод возвращает token бота для связи с сервером Telegram
     * @return token для бота
     */
    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "token";
    }

    
}
```

Код класса AppMain

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
                try {
                    TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
                    botsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
             
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SuperBot</groupId>
  <artifactId>Botyara</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
   <dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin><!-- Use latest to build recent Java applications -->
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

При этом,в еклипсе,программа продолжает работу.Пишу боту,получаю следующее:
[image: скрин]

Comment: "See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details" - вот это читали? Грубо говоря - slf это не логгер, а обёртка. И он хочет реальный логгер, поверх которого и будет работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить зависимость, и ошибка пропадет.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: спасибо,помогло. :)